# Excel - VBA: How to send multiple dynamic named ranges to a new instance of powerpoint

Tags: vba, excel

really hoping someone can help me.  I'm 'so so' with VBA but am in need of some assistance here.

I've scaled the internet and whilst I have found some examples, I don't know enough to tweak them to meet my needs so I was really hoping someone could help me please?

I have a report which will update regularly.  Within this report there are names ranges which dynamically update in length whenever criteria is changes via a pivot slicer etc.

I have the below code which takes one of the named ranges and copies it to a new instance of powerpoint (courtesy of: https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/3/17/copy-paste-an-excel-range-into-powerpoint-with-vba).

However, I need to adapt this to copy an array of named ranges and paste them in to the same instance of PowerPoint on the same slide.  The named ranges are "Top5Risks", "ActionsCompleted" and "UpcomingActions".

It would also be really good if someone could advise how I can set each of the positions of these within PowerPoint at time of paste so they aren't overlayed on one another but one in the top left, one top right and the other bottom left for example.  Here's the code I have so far:

```
Sub ExcelRangeToPowerPoint()

Dim rng As Range
Dim PowerPointApp As Object
Dim myPresentation As Object
Dim mySlide As Object
Dim myShape As Object

'One named range
Set rng = Worksheets("FX KPI Dashboard").Range("UpcomingActions")

'Create an Instance of PowerPoint
On Error Resume Next

'Is PowerPoint already opened?
  Set PowerPointApp = GetObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")

'Clear the error between errors
  Err.Clear

'If PowerPoint is not already open then open PowerPoint
  If PowerPointApp Is Nothing Then Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")

'Handle if the PowerPoint Application is not found
  If Err.Number = 429 Then
    MsgBox "PowerPoint could not be found, aborting."
    Exit Sub
  End If

On Error GoTo 0

'Optimize Code
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Create a New Presentation
Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Add


'Add a slide to the Presentation
Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides.Add(1, 11) '11 = ppLayoutTitleOnly

'Copy Excel Range
rng.Copy

'Paste to PowerPoint and position
mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2  '2 = ppPasteEnhancedMetafile
Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)

'Set position:
  myShape.Left = 66
  myShape.Top = 152

'Make PowerPoint Visible and Active
PowerPointApp.Visible = True
PowerPointApp.Activate

'Clear The Clipboard
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Any advice from you amazing folks would be really appreciated and very welcome.  My sanity depends on it! :)

Thanks

Sean

P.S. I'm running MS Office 2013

Comment: I'll be able to respond fully later -- away from my windows machine so can't look up my ppt VBA code.  Two approaches spring to mind: 1) play with the set position variables at the end of your code, create 3 sets for the 3 cases you want. 2) create a named object in powerpoint and use VBA to interrogate it, you can then paste into that object -- gives a lot of flexibility and robustness. (Option 2 means changing the code to load a preexisting ppt document [easy], or some stuff with hidden dummy presentations [awesome but potentially tricky]).

Answer (score 0):

I have not optimised your code (which is in parts very inefficient). Anyway, the below does now work.

The idea is you put the names of the named ranges that you would like to copy in `n_ranges` array. You must also define a counter to loop over all the named ranges in Excel and a counter (`n_counter`) to count when the named range you want occurs as you loop over all named ranges (`pos_hit`).

You was not clear where the other named ranges are (same sheet?) so I assumed they are in the same ActiveWorkbook.

In order to position the shapes, I have used 2 arrays that store the left and top attributes of the shape (`left_array`, `top_array`). Again, with no idea of the possible shape/size of your named ranges, you will have to play around with these values. There should be one entry in each array for every named range you copy. Note that powerpoint used points as the unit, with 72 points per inch (so 66 points is just under an inch). These are the new variables:

```
Dim n_counter As Integer
n_ranges = Array("Top5Risks", "ActionsCompleted", "UpcomingActions")

left_array = Array(66, 66, 516)
top_array = Array(152, 352, 152)
```

As we loop over all the named ranges in Activeworkbook, we need a way to determine if we have found a named range that you want to copy to powerpoint. We do this by including this small utility function. Paste it into your module, also. This is an additional utility function:

```
Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
  IsInArray = (UBound(Filter(arr, stringToBeFound)) > -1)
End Function
```

Because you said you wanted the shapes on the same slide of the same powerpoint, we have to move the code which creates a power point instance (and slide) outside of the loop (otherwise you will have multiple instances).

Putting it all together (with `IsInArray` at the bottom) you get :

```
Sub ExcelRangeToPowerPoint()

Dim rng As Range
Dim PowerPointApp As Object
Dim myPresentation As Object
Dim mySlide As Object
Dim myShape As Object

Dim n_counter As Integer
Dim pos_hit As Integer

pos_hit = 0
n_ranges = Array("Top5Risks", "ActionsCompleted", "UpcomingActions")

left_array = Array(66, 66, 516)
top_array = Array(152, 352, 152)

'Create an Instance of PowerPoint
On Error Resume Next

'Is PowerPoint already opened?
  Set PowerPointApp = GetObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")

'Clear the error between errors
  Err.Clear

'If PowerPoint is not already open then open PowerPoint
  If PowerPointApp Is Nothing Then Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")

'Handle if the PowerPoint Application is not found
  If Err.Number = 429 Then
    MsgBox "PowerPoint could not be found, aborting."
    Exit Sub
  End If

On Error GoTo 0

Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Add
Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides.Add(1, 11) '11 = ppLayoutTitleOnly

'One named range
For n_counter = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Names.Count

    If IsInArray(ActiveWorkbook.Names(n_counter).Name, n_ranges) Then
        Set rng = Range(ActiveWorkbook.Names(n_counter).Name)
        rng.Copy

        mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2  '2 = ppPasteEnhancedMetafile
        Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)

        myShape.Left = left_array(pos_hit)
        myShape.Top = top_array(pos_hit)

        pos_hit = pos_hit + 1
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If

Next

PowerPointApp.Visible = True
PowerPointApp.Activate

End Sub

Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
  IsInArray = (UBound(Filter(arr, stringToBeFound)) > -1)
End Function
```